# Tag Wikis - Please add and update them!

Tags: discussion

Recently, tags started showing their tag wikis when hovered over.  This site has very few tag wikis created, and it would be great if we could get those filled out for our more popular tags.

If you have the 1500 rep and the necessary upvotes for a tag, please consider adding the [tag wiki](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit-tag-wiki) or editing if it already there.

As a little incentive, editing an existing tag will earn you the [Tag Editor](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/badges/53/tag-editor) badge.  Furthermore, these edits count towards the [Strunk & White](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/badges/12/strunk-white) and [Copy Editor](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/badges/33/copy-editor) badges.

Comment: You realize you're only talking to 12 people right?  I mean you could upvote some more of my answers to help, but it's going to be a while. :)

Comment: @Neal - **anyone** can propose edits to the tag wikis now.

Comment: Actually it is the _Usage Guidance_ which is shown. But you are quite right, it is very useful to improve this.

Answer (score 1):

I had a go at making tag wikis for [arkham-horror](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags/arkham-horror/info) and [agricola](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags/agricola/info). Please take a look. It seems like most game tags will probably follow a similar template. I'd appreciate any feedback people here might have, either on these specific tags, or the more general format I've gone for, particularly if there is further information or other useful links that could be added.

I also added [Race for the Galaxy](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags/race-for-the-galaxy/info), but I need someone with more privileges to peer review it before it'll become visible.

Comment: Those look awesome, thanks!

Comment: Approving them as I see 'em, thanks again!  4k rep to edit any tag wiki I just noticed.  They must have snuck that in recently.

Comment: @Pat Ludwig - No worries. Ironically, it seems I am awarded 4 rep for each one of these 'untrusted wiki edits' - woohoo!

Comment: Yes, I did know that part.  You are limited to *only* 1000 rep total for such edits.  Therefore after 250 or 'em you can slow down some :)

Answer (score 1):

I created a tag wiki for [Power Grid](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags/power-grid/info) -- I probably could have been a little concise, but ended up going all-out.  Feel free to clean it up if the detailed section is *too* detailed.